# Extjs one store bind to more combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox, store

I have one problem about:one store bind to more comboboxes;

for example

combobox_1 bind to store_1, and the combobox_2 also bind to store_1 ,when expand the combobox_1, the store_1 is loaded. Then expand the combobox_2, the store_1 load again.

but I don't want to load the store_1 twice, because the store has been loaded already! How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could use seperate stores with same proxy.But if you dont want to go for pull requests twice,then you could use memory type for second store and just copy first store in second,if that is what you want.

Comment: can you post some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, on Controller, we will use a function on **load combo store event**:

```
init : function() {

   this.getNameComboStore().on('load', this.functionLoadStore, this); 

},

...

functionLoadStore : (store){

 if(store.count>0){
   store.suspendEvents(false); // break the load event (supends all events)
   store.resumeEvents(); // resume the event, it's IMPORTANT!
 }

}
```

In the function, we compare the number of elements charge, if count>0, supend the load event, and resume again.

Comment: I have use queryMode='local',solve this problem.Use this config,the the store will not load data from the remote.